# Solve Only variables should be passed by reference error Without Extra Variable

Tags: php

I have seen many topics on the subject but none talk about what I want. Is it possible to resolve this error without having to create a variable?

I'm trying to do this.

```
$video["upload"]["url"] = array_shift(array_column($json, 'url'));
```

But the error happens

```
Only variables should be passed by reference
```

This solves the problem

```
$var = array_column($json, 'url');
$video["upload"]["url"] = array_shift($var);
```

There are many occurrences, I will have to create many extra variables.
I do not like having to create those variables any more. Can you solve this error without doing this?

Comment: What's the goal? To get the first item from `array_column`? You don't actually want to *modify* the array, i.e. the `array_shift` operation as such is irrelevant to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it isn't possible because the method you want to access wants the variables passed by reference. Here the target-method is the problem. If you for example write an own method you have to decide if you want to have a variable passed by reference or by value. So you cannot influence extern written methods except you own the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function for this, so you only have to clutter your code once with an extra variable.